# How to choose and plot the quality criterion in `kml` function?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, longitudinal

I just started working with the `kml` package to perform longitudinal k-means clustering in `R`.

By default the `kml` function uses the `Calinski Harabatz Sorted` criterion to choose the 'best' clustering. So by accessing the 'best' clustering you will always see the `Calinski Harabatz Sorted` criterion.

***How*** can we **choose** another **quality criterion**?

---

A minimal example:

```
library(kml)
# some data
cld <- generateArtificialLongData(25)
# perform clustering
kml(cold)

# choose the 'best' clustering:
choice(cld)
```

This plots something like:

[image]

So we see the actual data, clustering and on the left side the quality criterion. Now for 'Calinski Harabatz Unsorted' the 'optimal' number is four clusters. But what if we choose another quality criterion?

To plot another solution with a differing number of clusters I can for example do:

```
plot(cld, 3, toPlot = 'both')
```

[image]

So here we see a clustering with three clusters and still the same criterion from above.

---

***How*** can we **plot** the quality criterion for another measure, e.g. **Ray and Turie**?

Comment: Excuse me, I don't have enough time to answer, this is a hint. `longitudinalData::CRITERION_NAMES; plotAllCriterion(cld, criterion=CRITERION_NAMES[1:5]); cld@criterionActif <- "Ray.Turi"; plot(cld,3,parMean=parMEAN(type="l"))
`

Comment: @cuttlefish44: This is it. Thx, again!